# Internet connectivity losses to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, routes, internet-connection

I have a master and two worker node architecture. I had single node and later added two nodes using `kubeadm`, I can see worker nodes when I use `kubectl get nodes`.

But cluster loses internet connectivity soon after workers joins.

I found this error when I try to deploy `nginx` web server to worker.

I have installed Cal as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

But it does not show `CoreDNS` pod with `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`.

When I use  `route -n` on a worker node :

```
$route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens32
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0          255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens32
192.168.100.1   192.168.100.222  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tunl0
192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0          255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens32
```

Here `192.168.100.1` is my network gateway server and `192.168.100.222` is my master node.

All 3 nodes running `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. As I described earlier, I had single node cluster and then I added two worker nodes using `kubeadm join`

I am really new to Kubernetes.What am I missing here?

Comment: how do you come to the conclusion that you lost internet connectivity.

Comment: @suren `ping google.com` and even `docker pull nginx` fails.

Comment: I assume you mean you can't ping google.com from the pod, not from the node.

Comment: @suren I can not ping from the *NODE*.

Comment: that's very strange. Node network should not be altered by adding it to a cluster. Do you know if you could ping google.com before adding the node to the cluster? Also when you do `kubectl get no`, these nodes are in ready state?

Comment: @suren yes, soon after reboot, I can ping to `google` from all nodes. but after few minutes all nodes loses this.

Comment: What OS do you use? How did you bootstrap your cluster (what flags did you pass)?  Can you post status of your pods?

Comment: @KFC_ I have updated the question. If you need more specific details, please ask.